# How to install super-wingpanel on ubuntu 16.04 Pantheon?

Tags: 16.04, pantheon

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/heathbar/super-wingpanel-daily/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/heathbar/super-wingpanel-daily/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
$ sudo apt-get install super-wingpanel
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package super-wingpanel
```

Comment: Please please please add more information!

Comment: @ubashu the error "does not have a release file" with the name of the PPA in question is usually sufficient to figure out what the problem is (PPA has no packages for the installed Ubuntu version) The question has been answered as such. It is not really unclear imho, though it is more-or-less a dupe of so many others.

Comment: @ubashu oh I see, sorry. I assumed the edit had just corrected the formatting. But I was mainly commenting for reviewers since this is in close votes queue as unclear. Maybe we can remove our comments now

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the launchpad website, you will find that super-wingpanel had only been released for Ubuntu Precise - No version exists for Ubuntu Xenial.  The package has not been updates in three years.

[image]